# Как получить историю перемещения?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть ли какая нибудь возможность получения данных об истории перемещения посредством API?

Поиск по данному вопросу меня ведет только к веб сервису гугла - [ссылка](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiW3rz0lfbSAhXCKCwKHdlZDMgQFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Flocationhistory%2Fb%2F0&usg=AFQjCNFJVp7Y6rcFv5qmPje0p2uwy-dwPw&sig2=T2JmYsxj66juQg2lBn1GMQ&bvm=bv.150729734,d.bGg&cad=rja)

Но мне требуется, например в приложении которым я занимаюсь, 
 авторизовываться в гугл сервисах, отправлять запрос на получение этих данных и отправлять на сервер - то есть автоматизировать этот процесс для определенного набора аккаунтов (возможно и одного на множество устройств)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет API для получения данных об истории местоположения.